# Opening Twitter share page in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an external url to open in a popup so I foind this code and I'm trying to get it to work.

This is what I've got:

The JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.get('http://www.mydomain.com/',function(data) {
    $(this).simpledialog({
        'mode' : 'blank',
        'prompt': false,
        'forceInput': false,
        'useModal':true,
        'fullHTML' : data
    });  
  });

});
```

The Link:

```
<a id="mylink" href="http://www.twitter.com/share?url=http://www.mydomain.com/somepage.html">
```

My problem is that it's not opening in a popup so I'm I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're running `simpledialog` on `this`, which in your JS is the AJAX object.  Change it to the following:

```
$("#mylink").simpledialog({ ... });
```